# Generating a JSON array of dicts using jq

Tags: arrays, jq

I'm trying to generate a JSON file from a bunch of values that I pass to jq through --arg parameters. The resulting format is correct, but the contents are tunring out unexpected:

```
$ jq --arg value_a0 1.1.1.1 --arg value_b0 81 --arg value_a1 2.2.2.2 --arg value_b1 82 --arg value_a2 3.3.3.3 --arg value_b2 83 '. | .nodes=[ .ip=$value_a0 | .port=$value_b0, .ip=$value_a1 | .port=$value_b1, .ip=$value_a2 | .port=$value_b2 ]' <<<'{}'
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "port": "83"
    },
    {
      "ip": "3.3.3.3",
      "port": "83"
    },
    {
      "ip": "2.2.2.2",
      "port": "83"
    },
    {
      "ip": "3.3.3.3",
      "port": "83"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was hoping to get:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "port": "81"
    },
    {
      "ip": "2.2.2.2",
      "port": "82"
    },
    {
      "ip": "3.3.3.3",
      "port": "83"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was hoping that the .nodes=[] would just summarise the results of operations separated by commas, but I'm obviously missing something. :(

Comment: Ok, after looking at this for a while, I now see the error of my ways. :)

I was thinking that "," operand separates <blah1> | <bleh1> from <blah2> | <bleh2>; but in fact it separates <bleh1> from <blah2>.

Sigh. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want in the manner of your attempt would be as follows:

```
jq -n --arg value_a0 1.1.1.1 --arg value_b0 81 --arg value_a1 2.2.2.2 --arg value_b1 82 --arg value_a2 3.3.3.3 --arg value_b2 83 '
  .nodes=[ {ip: $value_a0, port: $value_b0},
           {ip: $value_a1, port: $value_b1},
           {ip: $value_a2, port: $value_b2} ]'
```

Notice that -n can be used instead of '<<< {}'.

Using '=', one could similarly use the filter:

```
.nodes=[ (.ip=$value_a0 |.port=$value_b0),
         (.ip=$value_a1 |.port=$value_b1), 
         (.ip=$value_a2 |.port=$value_b2) ]
```

Using --arg in this manner, however, does seem very painful. There are probably many better or at least more flexible alternatives.  Consider, for example:

```
echo '"1.1.1.1" "81" "2.2.2.2" "82" "3.3.3.3" "83"' | jq -n '
  [{ip:inputs, port:input}]
'
```

Or if you don't want to have to quote the input strings:

```
cat << EOF | jq -R -n '[{ip: inputs, port: input}]'
1.1.1.1
81
2.2.2.2
82
3.3.3.3
83
EOF
```